# Unity iOS token request (Mobile Notifications)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I can't [get a token](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.notifications@1.4/manual/iOS.html). This request has infinite execution. It is not possible to receive an error message after the request to start investigating this problem. (Push notifications are enabled in the xCode project)

```
IEnumerator RequestAuthorization()
{
    var authorizationOption = AuthorizationOption.Alert | AuthorizationOption.Badge;
    using (var req = new AuthorizationRequest(authorizationOption, true))
    {
        while (!req.IsFinished)
        {
            yield return null;
        };
 
        string res = "\n RequestAuthorization:";
        res += "\n finished: " + req.IsFinished;
        res += "\n granted :  " + req.Granted;
        res += "\n error:  " + req.Error;
        res += "\n deviceToken:  " + req.DeviceToken;
        Debug.Log(res);
    }
}
```

If I disable the "Enable Push Notifications" flag in the "Mobile Notifications Settings" window, the request will be finished, but of course without the received token.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? If so, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Check that checkbox "Enable Push Notifications" is checked (Unity->Project Settings->Mobile Notifications).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).